# Installing Jenkins on Azure cloud

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I am trying to install jenkins on Azure portal using the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/configure-on-linux-vm

At the step where it asks to create the VM,

```
az vm create \
--resource-group QuickstartJenkins-rg \
--name QuickstartJenkins-vm \
--image UbuntuLTS \
--admin-username "azureuser" \
--generate-ssh-keys \
--custom-data cloud-init-jenkins.txt
```

It throws this error message:

```
Azure Error: InvalidTemplateDeployment
Message: The template deployment failed because of policy violation. Please see details for more information.
Exception Details:
        Error Code: RequestDisallowedByPolicy
        Message: Resource 'Jenkins-vmNSG' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers: '[{"policyAssignment":{"name":"Security groups shall not contain Internet ingress 0.0.0.0/0 rules for blocklisted ports - SSH"
```

Any idea how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: Looking on the error, you security policy in your Azure Subscription does not allow to have port 22 open to the world, where as image of your choosing `UbuntuLTS` has that port open.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@trailmax is right. The mentioned command creates a default Ubuntu VM with automatic SSH authentication, opening port `22` to all of Internet.

For security or compliance reasons, your subscription administrators have assigned policies that limit how resources are deployed to your Subscription, that's preventing you from deploying the VM with the default configuration. Hence the [RequestDisallowedByPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-policy-requestdisallowedbypolicy) error.

**Solution:** To resolve the issue, you can deploy the VM passing `--nsg-rule NONE` additionally, that will create the VM without the default NSG rule:

```
az vm create \
--resource-group QuickstartJenkins-rg \
--name QuickstartJenkins-vm \
--image UbuntuLTS \
--admin-username "azureuser" \
--generate-ssh-keys \
--custom-data cloud-init-jenkins.txt
--nsg-rule NONE
```

You can then [configure NSG rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-network-security-group#create-a-security-rule) to allow SSH from your Client IP only.